# How to execute web3 batch js file

Tags: web3js, compiler, batch

New to solidity programming and I discovered this today at this [site](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#batchrequest):

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
var batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'latest', callback));
batch.execute();
```

Which is great because I have been cutting and pasting a slew of web3 commands in the web3 console.

But I'm not sure how to actually execute a web3.js file containing the batch commands in the web3 console.

Would I say something like ./web3.js?

Not quite sure how to actually run the file containing the batch commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
>loadScript("/path/to/file/filename.js")
>yourFunction(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

`BatchRequest` feature is not for batching your requests into files.  It is for sending several Web3 RPC requests inside single HTTP(s) request.  See [JSON RPC documentation](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#batch) for details about how RPC batches work on low level.

What you probably need is either put your requests into separate `.js` file and load it via `loadScript("path/to/file.js");`.

Answer (score 0):

Developer advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here!

You can use web3.js to send batches of web3 requests. The following example shows how to send a batch to get the balance from multiple addresses.

> This method is much more efficient for this kind of use case compared to running a loop.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "YOUR_CHAINSTACK_ENDPOINT";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

const addresses = [
  "0x1f9090aaE28b8a3dCeaDf281B0F12828e676c326",
  "0x2bB42C655DdDe64EE508a0Bf29f9D1c6150Bee5F",
];

async function getBalances() {

  const startTime = Date.now()

  // Create a batch request object
  const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();

  // Loop through each address and add a getBalance request to the batch
  addresses.forEach((address) => {
    const request = web3.eth.getBalance.request(address, (error, balance) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        var timeFromStart = Date.now() - startTime
        console.log(`${address} has a balance of ${Number(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether')).toFixed(3)} ETH retrieved in: ${timeFromStart / 1000} seconds.`);
      }
    });
    batch.add(request);
  });

  console.log("Batch request:");
  console.log(batch.requests);

  // Send the batch request
  batch.execute();
}

getBalances();
```

You can learn more about batches and other methods to run this kind of request on the guide in the Chainstack developer portal: [HTTP batch request VS multicall contract](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/http-batch-request-vs-multicall-contract)